# Отправить post запрос python

Tags: python

Необходимо понять как следующий код представить в виде url:

```
custom_fields = {"0001" : "1234", "0002" : "4321"}
requests.post('https://site.com/test/',
data={
    'token' : '1234abcd',
    'custom_fields' : custom_fields
    })
```

То есть я бы мог отправить этот запрос следующим образом, но не ясно как использовать здесь словарь custom_fields

```
url = 'https://site.com/test/?token=1234abcd'
requests.request("POST", url)
```

Comment: Если сервер специально не ждёт информацию в `GET`-параметрах, то Вы не сможете её так отправить. Почему Вы решили, что можете так делать?

Answer (score 0):

Осуществить запрос представленный в виде "URL" можно  GET-запросом. В Вашем же случае, необходим все таки POST-запрос. Информация написанная ниже, взята [от сюда](https://steptosleep.ru/get-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B/).

> Если, в случае с GET-запросом, объем данных, которые мы могли передать ограничивался длиной адресной строки браузера, то в случае с запросом POST, такого ограничения нет, и мы можем передавать значительные объемы информации.

> Еще одно отличие метода POST от GET, метод POST скрывает все передаваемые им переменные и их значения, в своём теле (Entity-Body). В случае с методом GET они хранились в строке запроса (Request-URI).